# How to set Cron Job to empty cached directory

Tags: ssh, bash, cron

I have plain Ubuntu based server, i want to set Cron job and it will empty my website cache directory in every 24 hours, due to massive records '**rm -rf** ' not work, so manually i used '**find . -name '' | xargs rm**' to removed all cached files.

So i need solution to set Cron Job, and it will execute in every 24 hours to empty cache directory for me.

Thanks

Comment: Actually i doesn't understand what's your problem? In cron your task will look like:
0 1 * * * find . -name '"' | xargs rm

You don't know names of files or what? what's exact find command you are running?

Comment: i just need command to execute cron job to delete cache directory files, and cron job run in every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Run crontab -e and add

```
0 1 * * * find . -name 'HERE IS NAME' | xargs rm
```

This command runs in 1:00 AM.

Comment: How i can set directory path ? My cache directory path is: "/var/www/myweb/cache", i want to flush cache directory ?

Comment: I don't want what you want:) you need to specify your question and tell me what's doesn't work as expected. Yes if you directory /var/www/myweb/cache then command will look like:

0 1 * * * find /var/www/myweb/cache -type f -name 'HERE IS NAME' | xargs rm